# gitlab triggers jenkins project with parameters through webhook

Tags: jenkins, parameters, triggers, gitlab

My project in Jenkins has an "Extended Choise Parameter" parameter named action, which has three values:
build, burn, test, all of the three values are set as default values.

I also enable Generic Webhook Trigger and set a token string, and config
webhook  in my repo on Gitlab.

My targets are:

1. Trigger the poject in Jenkins manually if needed;
2. When new code merged to main branch on gitlab, trigger the project in
   Jenkins through webhook automatically;

There is my pipeline:

```
pipeline {
agent any
    
environment { 
def SRCCODE_DIR = "/var/jenkins_home/workspace/tmptest"

    _build="${sh(script:' echo $action|grep -w -o "build" || echo "error" ', returnStdout: true).trim()}"    
    _burn="${sh(script:' echo $action|grep -w -o "burn" || echo "error" ', returnStdout: true).trim()}" 
    _test="${sh(script:' echo $action|grep -w -o "test" || echo "error" ', returnStdout: true).trim()}" 
}

triggers {
    GenericTrigger(
        genericVariables: [ 
            [key: 'source_branch', value: '$.object_attributes.source_branch', expressionType: 'JSONPath'],
            [key: 'target_branch', value: '$.object_attributes.target_branch',  expressionType: 'JSONPath'],
            [key: 'action', value: '$.object_attributes.action',  expressionType: 'JSONPath'],
            [key: 'action_status', value: '$.object_attributes.state',  expressionType: 'JSONPath'],
   
            
        ],
        token: 'tmptest',

        regexpFilterText: '$target_branch_$action_status',
        regexpFilterExpression: 'main_merged',   
        
        causeString: 'new code merge to main',
        //printContributedVariables: true,
        printPostContent: true
    )

}



stages {
    
    stage("pull code") {
        when { environment name: '_build', value: 'build' } 
        steps {        
             println "pull code"
        }       
    }
    
    stage("build image") {
        when { environment name: '_build', value: 'build' } 
        steps {        
              println "build image"
        }       
    }
    
    stage("deploy image") {
       when { environment name: '_build', value: 'build' } 
        steps {        
            println "deploy image"
        }       
    }
    
    stage("send message") {
        when { environment name: '_build', value: 'build' } 
        steps {        
            println "send msg"
            
        }       
    }
    stage("burn image") {
       when { environment name: '_burn', value: 'burn' } 
        steps {  
            println "burn image"
        }       
    }
    
    stage("smoketest") {
        when { environment name: '_test', value: 'test' } 
        steps {  
            println "smoke test"

        }       
    }
    stage("mail report") {
        steps {        
            println "send testreport"
        }       
    }
        
}
```

}

When I trigger the project manually, it works well, all stages are executed.

but when it is triggered by webhook, only the last stage is executed,

I know there is smoething wrong, but I do not know where is wrong.
I am not goot at Jenkins , so is there any idea ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Extended choice is in "END OF FEATURE" state. Maybe you can use 3 boolean parameters at params or at input.

You don't need environ vars. You can use when - expression

Input step has some advantages over parameters. It have access to in-pipeline variables, parameters - only global params. But idea is a same:

```java
def action_params = [:]

pipeline {
  agent any
  triggers {
    GenericTrigger(
        genericVariables: [ 
          [key: 'source_branch', value: '$.object_attributes.source_branch', expressionType: 'JSONPath'],
          [key: 'target_branch', value: '$.object_attributes.target_branch',  expressionType: 'JSONPath'],
          [key: 'action', value: '$.object_attributes.action',  expressionType: 'JSONPath'],
          [key: 'action_status', value: '$.object_attributes.state',  expressionType: 'JSONPath'],               
        ],
        token: 'tmptest',
        regexpFilterText: '$target_branch_$action_status',
        regexpFilterExpression: 'main_merged',           
        causeString: 'new code merge to main',
        //printContributedVariables: true,
        printPostContent: true
        )
  }
  environment { 
    SRCCODE_DIR = "/var/jenkins_home/workspace/tmptest"
  }
  stages {    
    stage("input") {
      steps{
        script{
          catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', message: 'Using defaul vars') {
            timeout(time: 13, unit: 'SECONDS') {
              action_params = input(
                  message: 'select action',
                  parameters: [
                  booleanParam (
                    defaultValue: action == 'build',
                    description: 'Build',
                    name: 'build'),
                  booleanParam (
                    defaultValue: action == 'burn',
                    description: 'Burn',
                    name: 'burn'),
                  booleanParam (
                    defaultValue: action == 'test',
                    description: 'test',
                    name: 'test') ])
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    stage("Build") {
      when { expression {action_params.build ?: action == 'build'   } }
      stages{
        stage('Pull'){
          steps {        
            println "pull code"
          } 
        }    
        stage("build image") {
          steps {        
            println "build image"
          }       
        }
        stage("deploy image") {
          steps {        
            println "deploy image"
          }       
        }

        stage("send message") {
          steps {        
            println "send msg"
          }       
        }
      }
    }
    stage("burn image") {
      when { expression {action_params.burn ?: action == 'burn' } }
      steps {  
        println "burn image"
      }       
    }
    stage("smoketest") {
      when { expression {action_params.test ?: action == 'test'} }
      steps {  
        println "smoke test"
      }       
    }
    stage("mail report") {
      steps {        
        println "send testreport"
      }       
    }   
  }
}
```